# Access Dynamic Controls from another functions

Tags: vb.net, function, variables, dynamic

```
Private Sub btn_addNew_member_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_addNew_member.Click
    Dim myTabPage As New TabPage()
```

As this bottom clicked I created the controls by writing codes and setting locations and sizes. These controls are only created when the AddMember is clicked. After that , user will input the values in that tab pages,
[error when try to get a control from another sub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUF4Y.png)

```
Private Sub Resettt(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    full_box.Clear() ' full box is added in myTabPage and cannot access
End Sub
```

I add a dynamic tab page which also add many controls dynamically. I learned about how to handle the events of these dynamic controls by using "Add Handler" and "Remove Handler" and it worked well. But I also need to access the controls itself like the text from text boxes, selected indexes from combos by outside functions. But as they are built dynamic , I cannot access. I do research a lot but I still don't know how to solve it.

Comment: There's no such thing as "dynamic variables". If you declare variables in a method to refer to these controls when you create them then those are just local variables and thus cannot accessed outside the method they're declared in. You could declare member variables and use them to access the objects in any method but, as they're `TabPages`, you can simply use the `TabPages` property of the `TabControl` you added them to. If you mean inside the event handler, the `sender` parameter is a reference to the object that raised the event.

Comment: And I've told you how to do that.  All the `TabPages` you create are accessible via the `TabPages` collection you added them to in the first place.  The child controls on those `TabPages` are accessible via the `Controls` collections you added them to.  If you want to access a control in one of its event handlers then you use the `sender` parameter.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, thanks for ur answer. I mistakenly set the title as "Dynamic Variables", but what I really wanna do is to get access "Controls" from dynamic pages. My project is "Census Record". I used TabPages for family members and since I cannot know the number of members for particular family, I add dynamic Tab Pages.After that I need to access the inputs like texts, indexes, selections and so, I build functions to do these operations, but I faced errors with access level. Hope u can see the picture. Thanks again.

Comment: If you have code but it generates errors then post the code and provide the error messages and where they occur. We're not here to write your code for you or even necessarily tell you how to write your code but rather to help you fix code that doesn't do it's supposed to.  We can't do that without seeing the code in question.

Comment: I've already told you how to access the `TabPage` objects and the child controls on them.  If you're going to ignore that information then you're wasting my time and have nothing further to add.

Comment: tabControl_members.TabPages.myTabPage.full_box.clear(), I tried to use TabPages property as you told. But it is still showing "myTabPage" is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.TabControl.TabPageCollection'. I think it is because "myTabePage" do not exist when I called it from another function since it will create only when someone click certain button. If I am wasting your time somehow, sorry, dude. Thanks again

Comment: When you're provided with keywords, you're expected to use those keywords to do the appropriate research and find the rest of the information you're need. If you just try what you think might be convenient and then throw you're hands up when it doesn't work then you're not really trying. I've told you to use the `TabPages` property of the `TabControl`. Have you used the Help menu in VS to open the MSDN documentation and read about that property and how it actually works? If not, why not?